# Enterprise Architect: Package.Elements.count is coming as negative?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I shifted more than 30,000 elements from one package to another in EA, by darg and drop.
Now using c# addin when I try to check the count of destination package using:

```
package.Elements.Count
```

it is coming as -32101.
how is it possible.

I have three types of elements with three different stereotypes. How can I get the range (start index-end index) of each type of element?

I am trying to get the number of each type of elements using:

```
 for (short i = 0; i < 0-package.Elements.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if ((package.Elements.GetAt(i).Stereotype)=="Implementation-Data-Type")
                        {
                            impl_count=impl_count+1;
                        }
                        else if ((package.Elements.GetAt(i).Stereotype)=="Implementation-Data-Type-Element")
                        {
                            ele_count=ele_count+1;
                        }
                        else if ((package.Elements.GetAt(i).Stereotype)=="Sw-Data-Def-Props")
                        {
                            sw_count = sw_count+1;
                        }
                    }
```

but EA stops responding with this?
Also how can I find the starting and ending index of each type of element.?

Comment: the datatype short ranges from -32768 to 32767, this looks like an overflow. Is package.Elements.Count also of type short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [short](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) uses 16 bits to hold it's value, and can have a value of -32,768 to 32,767.

Unfortunately, EA uses a short to return Package and Element counts, so the most packages or elements a package can contain is 32,767. After that, it will rollover to -32,768.

This is a limitation of the EA SDK by the looks of it.

**Workarounds**

- You could group your elements into sub-packages, each with 30,000 elements in them.
- You could export the EA file to XML and work in XML.